# Android Firefox Nightly shows "HTTP CONNECT tunnel" after recent update

Tags: firefox, orbot

Firefox Nightly recently updated to the new UI they beta'd under the Firefox Preview moniker. The proxy settings I had in `about:config` got wiped out but reinstating the exact same settings is getting me the following message in the browser, presumably from Orbot itself:

> **This in HTTP CONNECT tunnel, not an HTTP proxy.**
>
> It appears you have configured your web browser to use  this Tor port as an HTTP proxy.
>
> This is not correct: This port is configured as a CONNECT tunnel, not an HTTP proxy. Please configure your client accordingly. You can also use HTTPS; then the client should automatically use HTTP CONNECT.
>
> See https://torproject.org/documentation.html for more information.

These are the `about:config` settings I've currently configured:

```
network.proxy.http = 127.1
network.proxy.http_port = 8118
network.proxy.socks = 127.1
network.proxy.socks_port = 9050
network.proxy.ssl = 127.1
network.proxy.ssl_port = 8118
network.proxy.type = 1
```

Orbot itself also shows it's active on those ports:
[image]

On the same device, F-Droid configured to use Tor also functions without issue. Granted, I can't see what ports it uses by default, but such settings has gone unchanged before or after the aforementioned Firefox update.

Comment: I have tried many time but not resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I solved it: removing `network.proxy.http` settings did the trick. Perhaps I didn't have this configured previously or the old Firefox Nightly automatically preferred the HTTPS proxy over the HTTP one and the behavior changed after the update, I don't know. Either way, there's no issue any more and everything is functioning as expected.

Comment: i am facing the same issue. let me know if have any solution which we can do it programmatically